# Que información se puede extraer de una url

Tags: python, web, url

Utilizo python y tengo una serie de URLs. Algunas son semanticas otras no. (son códigos alfanuméricos).

Me gustaría saber que información se puede extraer de una URL a día de hoy (nada de scrapping ni código fuente de la página, solo la URL)

Por ejemplo:
- ¿Podríamos decodificar las url no semanticas?
- ¿las URLs semanticas las podríamos codificar de una manera sencilla?
- ¿Podríamos saber cosas como la publicidad (parametro gclid), compras en retailers, etc.?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Los formatos de las urls no están estandarizados, más allá de las diferentes "partes" que la componen (protocolo, "://",  [nombre de usuario y clave, opcionales "@"] nombre_del_sitio [:puerto opcional]/ruta "?" query "#" fragmento). La parte de la ruta es totalmente libre con tal de que no contenga ciertos caracteres. Se supone jerárquica pero cada servidor la organiza como quiera. La parte de la query es una secuencia de clave=valor separados por `&`. No hay jerarquía y su significado depende de cada servidor. La parte del fragmento no se envía al servidor.

Comment: Si bien no hay un estándar para la información contenida en las direcciones url, podrias buscar en cada dirección, las que sean de mayor relevancia para ti, de modo que puedas crear un objeto de salida con la información disponible de cada url. Creo que está claro que dicho objeto hipotético, tendría inicializadas sólo algunas variables (las que estén presentes en la dirección), pero no sé si esta forma de recopilar información, te servirá para lo que tienes pensado hacer.

Comment: supongo que lo conoces, pero [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) permite fragmentar una URL en sus partes básicas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No existe un criterio unificado para la formación de urls así que no, no hay información extra (ademas del protocolo: https, mailto, file, por poner algunos).